# Scale cosine similarity between vectors to range 0, 1?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, angle

I am interested in calculating similarity between vectors, however this similarity has to be a number between 0 and 1. There are many questions concerning tf-idf and cosine similarity, all indicating that the value lies between 0 and 1. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Soft_cosine_measure):

> In the case of information retrieval, the cosine similarity of two
>   documents will range from 0 to 1, since the term frequencies (using
>   tf–idf weights) cannot be negative. The angle between two term
>   frequency vectors cannot be greater than 90°.

The peculiarity is that I wish to calculate the similarity between two vectors from two different word2vec models. These models have been aligned, though, so they should in fact represent their words in the same vector space. I can calculate the similarity between a word in `model_a` and a word in `model_b` like so

```
import gensim as gs
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

model_a = gs.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_a_path, binary=False)
model_b = gs.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_b_path, binary=False)

vector_a = model_a[word_a].reshape(1, -1)
vector_b = model_b[word_b].reshape(1, -1)

sim = cosine_similarity(vector_a, vector_b).item(0)
```

But `sim` is then a similarity metric in the [-1,1] range. Is there a scientifically sound way to map this to the [0,1] range? Intuitively I would think that something like

```
norm_sim = (sim + 1) / 2
```

is okay, but I'm not sure whether that is good practice with respect to the actual,  mathematical meaning of cosine similarity. If not, are other similarity metrics advised?

Comment: What are you using norm_sim for? Norm_sim is monotonic in sim; is that good enough? Another option is to force both vectors to be positive so that their cosine similarity to be positive.

Comment: `norm_sim` will be used in a machine learning experiment of a colleague. The prerequisite is that all values are between 0 and 1. I am not sure how I can force vectors to be positive during training. I don't think that is possible, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check out the wiki page:
[cosine_similarity_wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Angular_distance_and_similarity), there it discusses how to convert the cosine similarity to angular distance.

In numpy:

```
import numpy as np
angular_dis = np.arccos(cos_sim) / np.pi
```

You can also see it as the answer with 0 votes on the post:
[stackoverflow_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064630/how-do-i-convert-between-a-measure-of-similarity-and-a-measure-of-difference-di).